# While using jquery with prototypejs, is there any way we can remove all prototypejs variables from global scope instead of jquery

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, conflict

I know we can use jQuery.noConflict() to resolve the conflict between the 2 libraries, but I want to use $ for jquery & something else for prototypejs. Is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype doesn't provide any option similar to jQuery.noConflict(), as far as I know.