# PrototypeJS: Is it possible to remove or undo its global modifications?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Is it possible to kill all non-original extensions from prototype, such as array.each, array.map, function.bind, etc?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242269/while-using-jquery-with-prototypejs-is-there-any-way-we-can-remove-all-prototyp) states that there is no version of noConflict, but I'm not looking to reclaim the $. I want to remove everything that prototype did to the host objects.

Comment: Prototype is pretty self-referential. I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I didn't think so either, but I figured it couldn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very easy way to do this: **Do not include prototype at all.** That's pretty much the only solution.

Comment: Yep, if I couldn't, I wouldn't include it. Unfortunately, there's nothing I can do.

Answer (score 0):

In this case Prototype's Array.prototype methods are removed. It gets reset back to default. Do the same with anything else you want to reset (Function, etc.)

```
for(var i in Array.prototype)
        delete Array.prototype[i]
```